# Java string.equals function for inequality?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison, inequality

This code compares text entered by the user (**userText**) with a keyword (**endProgram**). When the user enters the word **exit**, the program will complete and close.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String endProgram = "exit";
    String userInput;

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        userInput = input.nextLine();
    } while ( !(userInput.equals(endProgram)) );

}
```

Is there a better way to write the code within the while parenthesis?
 That is, instead of using  `!(String.equals(String))` is there another function to compare inequality?

Comment: What's wrong with using `!`?

Comment: That's the right way to do it.

Comment: Actually you can use `!userInput.equals(endProgram)` (without parenthesis) if that looks ugly to you

Comment: I would use `userInput.compareToIgnoreCase(endProgram) == 0`, so that `"exit"` and `"EXIT"` are treated the same way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be != 0 instead of == 0?

Comment: Or better yet (can't edit comments after 5 min...): `!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(endProgram)`.
And yes, it would be `!= 0`.

Comment: I tried the .equalsIgnoreCase and it works great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that ! is just one character, there's not much point in having a separate inequality test function that would just return the negation of the equality function.
So no.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.compareTo(String)` which would return `0` when Strings are the same. It is more general than `String.equals(String)` as it performs lexical comparison and can be used for ordering (i.e. `"a" < "b"`). It has an `compareToIgnoreCase()` variant which would be better in your case as `"EXIT"` sounds just as valid as `"exit"`.

The `equals()` method is actually performing comparison on an `Object`, not a `String` (though it will fail if the `Object` is not an instance of `String`). Its `equalsIgnoreCase()` variant though, is taking a `String` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the **"equal approach"** (but the code you just wrote is right), you could use an `integer` as exit condition.

In  that case, I suggest the use of `hasNextInt()`.